# Yeoman "yo build:minify" or ""yo build" fails on Win7

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying to get the latest version of generator-angular working Win7x64.  I've installed generator angular using "npm install -g  generator-angular."  If create a project with **yo angular** and then run **yo build:minify** I get the following error:

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name build:minify installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 15 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

If I create a project with **yeoman init angular** and then run **yeoman build** I successfully get

```
Done, without errors.
```

I believe the **Yeoman** command is outdated.  Thoughts on how to get **yo** working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ yeoman build` became `$ grunt build`.

Please read the [migration guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20130925003911/http://yeoman.io/migrate.html).

Comment: Guess what happened in between. Fortunately, we have the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130925003911/http://yeoman.io/migrate.html